# Nothing in fetching data using Cordova SQLite in Intel XDK

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, intel-xdk

I'm developing a Hybrid App using Intel XDK and power of Cordova. For using SQLite I'm using [cordova-sqlite-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-sqlite-storage) BUT have problem to fetch the data ! I'm using this codes ...

```js
function onDeviceReady() {
 var appDataBase = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'DB.db', location: 1}, onSuccess_DB, onFail_DB);
 getPageContent('about-app', 'page-about');
}

function getPageContent(pageID, outputDIV) {
 appDataBase.transaction(function(dbDataSet) {
  dbDataSet.executeSql("SELECT page_content FROM app_pages WHERE page_id='" + pageID + "'", [], function(dbDataSet, dbDataOutput) {
   if (dbDataOutput.rows.length == 1) {
    console.log('Get Page Content : ' + pageID);
    $('#' + outputDIV).html(dbDataOutput.rows.item(0).page_content);
   } else {
    console.log('Get Page Content : Count ERROR : ' + dbDataOutput.rows.length);
    $('#' + outputDIV).html('NOT Found');
   }
  }, function(e) {
   console.log('Get Page Content : DB ERROR : ' + e.message);
  });
 });
}
```

What shall I do !?

Answer (score 0):

Check with this code

```
function getData(last) {

    db.transaction(function (tx) {
          alert("get data");
        var query = "SELECT firstname, lastname, acctNo FROM customerAccounts WHERE lastname = ?";
           alert("get data working");
        tx.executeSql(query, [last], function (tx, resultSet) {

            for(var x = 0; x < resultSet.rows.length; x++) {
                alert("First name: " + resultSet.rows.item(x).firstname +
                    ", Acct: " + resultSet.rows.item(x).acctNo);
            }
        },
        function (tx, error) {
            alert('SELECT error: ' + error.message);
        });
    }, function (error) {
        alert('transaction error: ' + error.message);
    }, function () {
        alert('transaction ok');
    });
}
```